# help understanding what's possible with source control integration into issue tracking software

Tags: version-control, issue-tracking

This is related to (but not identical to) "[How important is version control integration with your bug tracking software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954242/how-important-is-version-control-integration-with-your-bug-tracking-software)"

I am currently using JIRA as issue/task tracking software with a small team, for potential evaluation for broader use in our company. Because we use SurroundSCM, and JIRA does not support either SurroundSCM or the general SCCI, I can't use the two together and I have a hard time understanding the tangible benefits of integration with issue tracking + source control integration.

If you are experienced in this area, could you please post (one feature per answer please) a tangible example of how issue tracking + source control integration has made your job easier / more reliable? I can only think of one area which I will post too.

Answer (score 0):

**Easily referencing issues in source-control commits, and source-control revisions in issues.**

If the source control software and issue tracking systems have a web interface, then it's possible to use URLs as linkage, but this is kind of cumbersome.